# How change `wrapfigure` position in LaTeX?

Tags: wrapfigure

I used `wrapfig` package in my LaTeX. But it showed:

[image]

Of course, the picture had not been displayed in full.
Below the picture is the page boundary. How can it be put here? How can I change its position?
My code is

```
\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{0.5\linewidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[angle=270,width=0.5\textwidth]{three.JPG}
    \caption{two}
    \label{fig:one}
  \end{wrapfigure}
```

Comment: First, using {R} instead of {r} will delay wrapfig until a paragraph start where the image will fit.  Second, IIRC inside wrapfig (as with a minipage) `\textwidth` changes to the width of the wrapfig.

Comment: @JohnKormylo Using `R` can make it showed in full. May you tell me what is the `IIRC`? If I don't use `\textwidth`, the picture will be distorted to too hight.

Comment: @JohnKormylo There is too much blank before and after the picture wrapped. May you tell how to reduce the gap before and after the picture with text?

Comment: I stand corrected.  A quick experiment showed that `\the\textwidth` was unchanged.  Sorry about that.

Comment: @JohnKormylo Thanks for your reply. You help me a lot. Thanks.

Comment: Wrapfig adds `\intextsep` above and below, same as a figure [h].  You can always add `\vskip-\intextsep` at the top and/or bottom inside the wrapfigure, or set `\intextsep=0pt` temporarily.

Comment: @JohnKormylo I am not familiar with LaTeX.  I add `\vskip\intextsep` at the top and bottom. But it changes nothing.

Comment: Try `\vspace*{-\intextsep}`.  Don't forget the minus.

Comment: @JohnKormylo `\begin{wrapfigure}{R}{0.5\textwidth}
    \vspace*{-\intextsep} ..... \vspace*{-\intextsep}    \end{wrapfigure}` It is still no use.

Answer (score 1):

They work fine for me:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx, wrapfig}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[2]

\begin{wrapfigure}{R}{0.5\textwidth}
\vskip-\intextsep
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}
\vskip-\intextsep
\end{wrapfigure}

\lipsum[1]

{\intextsep=0pt
\begin{wrapfigure}{R}{0.5\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}
\end{wrapfigure}

\lipsum[1]\par}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for your example. Your example shows the result I wanted. Maybe my template my classmate made and sent to me, has some limits on this function.